# how to react on submit in Page_Load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pageload

i have many radio buttons:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="selectedYesNoQuestionBlock1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="Question1GotAnswered" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="selectedYesNoQuestionBlock2" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Question2GotAnswered">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

etc.

for each radio button i have their method:

```
protected void Question1GotAnswered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {}
```

i want to react on this in Page_Load before method Question1GotAnswered() will be called. i'am trying it but everything is unsuccessuful.

tried something like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 if (sender.ToString() == "Question1GotAnswered")
                    {}
}
```

please help i need it much!

Comment: What you're trying to do is end run around the basic .NET event order.  May I ask - why?

Comment: should i do initialising in constructor instead methods for questions?

Comment: Is that intended to be an answer to my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do it is to check the `if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == control.ClientID) { }` to see that the control posting back is the given control that caused the postback.  So this should be the ID of your radio button causing the postback.

HTH.